# How to make a resizable html table on mouse drag?

Tags: html-table, resize, drag

I want to create a table in html with 2 columns and 3 rows but it should resize if we drag mouse from its corner.

Answer (score 2):

Use colResizable, a [jquery plugin to resize html tables and columns](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/)

example html

```
<table id="sample">
    <tr> <td>cell</td> <td>cell</td> <td>cell</td> </tr>
</table>
```

example js:

```
$("#sample").colResizable({liveDrag:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery UI](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20ui&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://jqueryui.com/&ei=K_uYT9nmM4WSiAex2snpBQ&usg=AFQjCNGozghm2ayt4t8eDFJl92PWcMmhZQ&cad=rja), which has a [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable) function to make a HTML element, e.g. a table, resizable.